# Form.Show vs Form.ShowDialog Cross Threading

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, devexpress

I have the following code which closes a `loginform` and opens the `mainform`

```
Sub Loadform(ByVal formName As Form)
    Dim Thisform As Form = DirectCast(formName, frmLogIn1)
    Thisform.Hide()
    Dim frm As New frmMain
    frm.ShowDialog() <- Problem
    Thisform.Close()
End Sub
```

The mainform has a *DevExpress* SplashScreenManager which loads and unloads the splash screen automatically.

When I call `frm.Show` I get a cross thread exception when the SplashScreen closes.

If I call it using `frm.ShowDialog` it works OK. This inst new code. The application is approx 12 months old and this code was added at the start, however I am now having problems.

The original code (taken from a backup) is:

```
Me.Hide()
Dim main As New frmMain
main.Show()
Me.Dispose()
```

But that seems to be closing the mainform now.

Any ideas?

Comment: Based on the old backup code. That is probably happening from the Shutdown mode settings which can be found in the Application tab of the properties setting for the solution. Ensure that it is not set to When startup form closes because that would cause this behavior.

Comment: The shutdown mode is : When last form closes. Besides, that shouldn't affect thread cross call?

Comment: I am afraid that the description of the problem will not help to understand it in this particular case. What might be helpful is the full exception callstack obtained in Visual Studio (not from the Exception object). Better - the callstack by all threads. Could you add this information to this question?

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand your question. Do you want to use the old code? The new? What problem are you trying to solve?

Well, an explanation for you calling frm.Show() and Thisform.Close() is simple.
When you call frm.Show() the new form is opened on a second thread and the current form continues to execute its code normally, logically reaching a line of code Thisform.Close () in which it closes. Because it is the main form, when it is closed it tries to terminate all other forms, so it tries to close the form you just opened, so the cross-thread exception occurs (remember that the new form is Running on another thread ;) )

But when you call frm.ShowDialog () the operation is different. It does not start a new thread, it just directs to the new form, so any line of code after ShowDialog only runs when the new forum is closed;

Comment: All I am trying to do if close the login form, show the splash screen and close the splash screen when the main form is finished loading. The old code used to do that without any exceptions but now it won't.